# "Everyone working on this together has come to a different conclusion" or "conclusions"?

Tags: pronouns, singular-vs-plural

> Everyone working on this together has come to a different conclusion.

Since everyone work on this come to a different conclusions, why "a different **conclusion**" instead of "different **conclusions**"?

Comment: BTW, "Since everyone *working* on this *came* to a different *conclusion*"

Answer (score 1):

Either one is OK. Viewpoint is a bit different.

> Everyone working on this together has come to **a different conclusion**.

This is from the viewpoint of each *conclusion*.

> Everyone working on this together has come to **different conclusions**.

This is from the viewpoint of *this (the problem)*. The problem has several conclusions.

Answer (score -3):

first of all the word to identify this is that - try to find the words that can make your choice perfect, think English as the language with more logical understanding needed, this much only.

key to your question is the word "**a**", have a different conclusion or a different conclusions.

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about. I want to know why "a different conclusion" is correct instead of "different conclusions" in that sentence.

Comment: see the usage of word a, hoe can the words a different conclusions can come into the scenario, using plural form with a, here a signifies singularity so , use singular form,
otherwise look at this 
a different conclusion from lots of available options/ conclusions